# next_permutation with custom comparer function c++

Tags: c++, permutation

I'm using a custom comparer function for my next_permutation function, but I don't understand why I'm getting the error:

```
Expression: invalid operator<
```

I want my function to work with at least these restrictions in the function body, but keep getting errors:

```
bool mycomp(int i, int j)
{
    return (((i < 0) && (j > 0)) || ((i > 0) && (j < 0)));
};
```

but when I do it like this, it works fine:

```
bool mycomp(int i, int j)
{
    return (((i < 0) && (j > 0)));
};
```

I want to also add another restriction, but don't know how.
here is the relevant code with the next_permutation function:

```
int counter, size, *guests;
for (int i = 2; i <= 9; i++)
{
    size = i * 2;
    counter = 1;
    guests = new int[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j += 2)
    {
        guests[j] = counter;
        guests[j + 1] = 0 - counter;
        ++counter;
    }
    sort(guests, guests + size);
    counter = 0;
    while (next_permutation(guests, guests + size, mycomp))
    {
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

I also understand that there is a strict weak ordering requirement. I understood the gist of it after reading about it, but not sure exactly how it applies to this situation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you think the custom comparator function does?  What do you think it *means* to use a given custom comparator?  Your use of "restriction" is a red flag to me.

Comment: There is no error using your first function: live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8abe254b696f6df8

Comment: @Stephen : it is silently failing. The OP has the chance to get a debug assert checking the validity of its comparator

Comment: @Yakk then I don't think I know what a custom comparator is for. I will try look it up. In this case I thought it was used to put restrictions on the permutations to minimize the amount of permutations found.

Comment: @Yakk what does the custom comparator do in the next_permutation function?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is trying to tell you (through a runtime assertion) that your comparator is invalid. It is invalid as it does not respect the strict weak ordering contract for at least two reasons :

1) It is not *antisymmetric* ( ie f(x, y) implies !f(y, x)) :

```
std::cout << mycomp(2, -3) << '\n';
std::cout << mycomp(-3, 2) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

2) It is not *transitive* (ie f(x, y) and f(y, z) imply f(x, z) ):

```
std::cout << mycomp(2, -3) << '\n';
std::cout << mycomp(-3, 2) << '\n';
std::cout << mycomp(2, 2) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
false
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/888b1bfd43f73d5c)**

Your probably need to rethink your problem, and how you really want to order your elements while doing the permutations.

Comment: Your example doesn't disprove that its antisymmetric. You should pick `f(2,-3)` instead.

Comment: @Barry thank you for the reply, but your output doesn't seem correct for 2). i will ponder on your answer and try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Permutation is about ordering.  The default ordering is `1<2<3<4<5<6` etc -- the order you are used to.

The custom comparator lets you set an ordering that is different than the default one.

This is useful in a number of situations.

For a toy example, you could set all even numbers to be greater than all odd ones -- `1<3<5<7<...<0<2<4<6<8<...`.

Example implementation that leverages `std::tuple`:

```
std::tuple<bool,unsigned> myhelper( unsigned x ) {
  return std::make_tuple( !(x%2), x );
}
bool myorder( unsigned lhs, unsigned rhs ) {
  return helper(lhx)<helper(rhs);
}
```

For types that don't have an operator `<` that is a strict weak ordering, it lets you provide one.  A complex number can be ordered lexicographically, or magnitude-wise: the magnitude-ordering is not a strict weak ordering, and having `<` be a lexicographic order would be surprising.